# Serializing private member data

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, serializable

I'm trying to serialize an object to XML that has a number of properties, some of which are readonly.

```
public Guid Id { get; private set; }
```

I have marked the class [Serializable] and I have implemented the ISerializable interface.

Below is the code I'm using to serialize my object.

```
public void SaveMyObject(MyObject obj)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(_location);
    serializer.Serialize(tw, obj);
    tw.Close();
}
```

Unfortunately it falls over on the first line with this message.

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled:
>   Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS0200: Property or indexer 'MyObject.Id' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

If I set the Id property to public it works fine. Can someone tell me if I'm doing something, or at least if its even possible?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could use `DataContractSerializer` (but note you can't use xml attributes - only xml elements):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
[DataContract]
class MyObject {
    public MyObject(Guid id) { this.id = id; }
    [DataMember(Name="Id")]
    private Guid id;
    public Guid Id { get {return id;}}
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
        var obj = new MyObject(Guid.NewGuid());
        using(XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out)) {
            ser.WriteObject(xw, obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement `IXmlSerializable` and do everything yourself - but this works with `XmlSerializer`, at least.

Comment: I've changed my code to use the DataContractSerializer and I've noticed that its still running the GetObjectData method. Am I right in thinking that I can either put attributes on my properties to serialize them, or I can implement the ISerializable interface?

Comment: If you implement ISerializable (or is it IXmlSeializable?), you're basically doing all the work yourself...

Comment: This worked for me, but later I found out that serializing private members with the DataMemberAttribute only works when running in full trust environment, not in partial trust. A solution is making the member internal instead of private. For details see http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/wcf-and-datacontract-serialization-internals-and-tips-.html.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer`. It is more powerful and fixes some issues of the classic Xml Serializer.

Note that there are different attributes for this one.

```
[DataContract]
public class X
{
  [DataMember]
  public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}


NetDataContractSerializer serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(_location);
serializer.Serialize(tw, obj);
```

**Edit:**

Update based on Marc's comment: You should probably use `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer` for your case to get a clean XML. The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: NetDataContractSerializer doesn't write xml... - or rather, it isn't clean xml suitable for external consumption - it has assembly metadata in it.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for the hint. It always depends on what one wants to achieve. DataContractSerializer is probably what is expected here.

Answer (score 2):

Read only fields will not be serialized using the `XmlSerializer`, this is due to the nature of the `readonly` keyword

From MSDN:

> The *readonly* keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

So... you would pretty much need to set the fields value in the default constructor...

Comment: I thought that because I had implemented the ISerializable.GetObjectData method the XmlSerializer would use that to get the information I wanted to serialize, and not try and access my read only properties.

Comment: XmlSerializer doesn't care about ISerializable - only IXmlSerializable

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with that particular serialization mode (see the other comments for workarounds). If you really want to leave your serialization mode as-is, you have to work around the framework limitations on this one. See this [example](http://en.allexperts.com/q/VB-NET-3306/Class-Serialization.htm)

Esentially, mark the property `public`, but throw an exception if it's accessed at any time other than deserialization.

Comment: "but throw an exception" - since XmlSerializer doesn't support serialization callbacks, you have no way of knowing...

Comment: You could use `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` to find out what's calling your property, but I wouldn't recommend such a solution :-)