# Raise a Visual Studio warning when using an empty property setter

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, serializable

I need to make a class Serializable.
In this class I have a MyGuid readonly property, that I want to be serializable but not deserializable (property is initialized in a backing field).
Using base serialization .NET features, you know, have a reandonly property make deserialization fail, 'cause it cannot deserialize a readonly property.
So I decide to create a public get-set MyGuid property with a backing field, and make setter do nothing:

```
[Serializable]
public class Task : ITask
{
    private readonly Guid m_guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    public MyGuid Guid
    {
        get { return m_guid; }
        set { /*Empty setter!*/ }
    }
}
```

Now I don't want to shoot in my foot...
There's a way I can make setter of MyGuid property as "deprecable" or "disabled"?
It would be nice have Visual Studio warning me if I try to use the setter.

Or, instead, there's a better way to manage this kind of needs?

Thank you!

**Edit:** Found something here: [Serializing private member data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802711/serializing-private-member-data) I'm reading...

Comment: If you're not going to ever deserialise it, why serialise it? Could you use the `[NonSerialized]` or `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]` attributes on the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Guid Guid
{
    get { return m_guid; }
    set { if (value != null) Debugger.Log(0, "Warning", "This property has an empty setter, just for serializing purpose!"); }
}
```

This if you accidentally set the value yourself, you'll get a warning in the debug window. On the other hand, you absolutely need the setter for the serializer, or otherwise the deserializer would never be able to appoint the property a value after reading it from the file! So the setter is not for you but for the serializer to function normally.

Comment: Mmm, nice solution!  
The exact code is this:  
if (value != null)  
{  
Debugger.Log(0, "Warning", "This property has an empty setter, just for serializing purpose!");  
}

Comment: Where I have to look for the Debugger message in VS2010?

Comment: Follow the menu: `View > Output > Show output from > Debugger`. It also gets displayed automatically right next to the locals window, as soon as you start debugging your application (hitting F5).

Comment: Ok, thank you. But it is not too much visible, there...
I will continue to look for a stronger solution, I really care to my feet! :-)

Comment: You're welcome. If you really need a strong signal, use `Debugger.Break();` :)

Comment: It' true, nice! :-) This oneis my favourite. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont include the set, it will auto know its read only, so wont let you set it. It would then flag errors in your code when you try

Comment: His point is that you have to include the set for the serialization to work. He just wants it flagged is he(or anyone else) tries to use the property set in code.

Comment: If I don't include the set my class would not be serializable... :-)