# Where do I put the [XmlAttribute] attribute in c#?

Tags: c#, attributes, xml-attribute

I am changing some public field to private by providing corresponding public property.

for example:

```
public string Name;
```

is change to

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get{ return _name;}
    set{ _name = value;}
}
```

However, what about the [XmlAttribute] attribute on the original public field? 
i.e. does

```
[XmlAttribute]
public string Name;
```

becomes:

```
[XmlAttribute]
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get{ return _name;}
    set{ _name = value;}
}
```

or

```
private string _name;
[XmlAttribute]
public string Name
{
    get{ return _name;}
    set{ _name = value;}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

second solution.

By the way, you don't need anymore (.net 3.0 and +) a private field, if you don't do anything special in getter or setter.

You can use [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
[XmlAttribute]
public string Name {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thank you Raphael, the reason i do that is because the Sonar(code quality control) detects the public string Name; with the following rule: [link](https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme/wiki/Gendarme.Rules.Design.AvoidVisibleFieldsRule(2.10))

Comment: @IC_Weekend well... because the property is public, while the field is private. And default serialization can't work on private fields. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802711/serializing-private-member-data

Comment: @IC_Weekend yes, use public fields is not a good idea, but your Sonar will accept auto-implemented properties (if it doesn't, change it ;) )

Answer (score 1):

And instead of doing

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
get{ return _name;}
set{ _name = value;}
}
```

why not do

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I think this was introduced in C# 3.0