# WebAPI List<T> Serialization XML/JSON output

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I tried to create a method in a **ApiController** that looks like this:

```
public DemoList<Demo> GetAll()
{
    var result = new DemoList<Demo>() { new Demo(){Y=2}, new Demo(), new Demo(){Y=1} };
    result.Name = "Test";
    return result;
}
```

Demo and DemoList look like this:

```
public interface INamedEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Demo
{
    public int X { get { return 3; } }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

public class DemoList<T> : List<T>, INamedEnumerable<T>
{
    public DemoList()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

I then cheked the ouput with fiddler

```
GET http://localhost:8086/api/Demo
```

and got the following:

**XML** (Accept header set to application/xml)

`<ArrayOfDemo xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXX.WebAPI"><Demo><Y>2</Y></Demo><Demo><Y>0</Y></Demo><Demo><Y>1</Y></Demo></ArrayOfDemo>`

JSON (Accept header set to application/json)

`[{"X":3,"Y":2},{"X":3,"Y":0},{"X":3,"Y":1}]`

My question is quite simple: Why is the X variable not serialized with the XML version (I thought that readonly properties were serialized) **and more important, why in both cases is the `Name` property (which is writable) not serialized??**
What are the alternatives to make this work like I expected?

*Edit: 
Please, note that I'm in a WebAPI context! By default, the XmlSerializer is automatically set to XmlMediaTypeFormatter and the JSONSerializer to JsonMediaTypeFormatter*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug... using the following workaround made the trick:

```
public class ListWrapper<T>
{
    public ListWrapper(INamedEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        List = new List<T>(list);
        Name = list.Name;
    }

    public List<T> List { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XML serializers only allows serialization of properties with "set" provided.

Comment: Then why is `Name` not serialized? By the way, see my edit, I'm not using this serializer

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to serialize it? If you don't need attributes you could use DataContractSerializer as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802711/serializing-private-member-data). By default properties without a set are not serialized however using DataContractSerializer or implementing IXmlSerializable should do the trick for you.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
[DataContract]
class MyObject {
    public MyObject(Guid id) { this.id = id; }
    [DataMember(Name="Id")]
    private Guid id;
    public Guid Id { get {return id;}}
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
        var obj = new MyObject(Guid.NewGuid());
        using(XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out)) {
            ser.WriteObject(xw, obj);
        }
    }
}
```