# SGen can not generate an assembly for a valid type

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, sgen

I have a valid for a XmlSerializer type:

```
public class MyItem
{
  public MyItem() {
    Values = new List<string>();
  }

  public List<string> Values { get; private set; }
}
```

It successfully serialized and deserialized (Full code example here http://ideone.com/s2PvSB). But, I can not generate .XmlSerializers.dll for this type, SGen failed with:

```
Microsoft (R) Xml Serialization support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.33440]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
EXEC : error : Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
EXEC : error CS0200: Property or indexer 'TestSGen.MyItem.Values' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

SGen called from a PostBuild event as

```
"$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)SGen.exe" /Assembly:"$(TargetFileName)" /Type:"TestSGen.MyItem" /Force
```

Is it a bug in SGen or [somewhere] documented behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing private member data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802711/serializing-private-member-data)

Comment: @HansPassant It's not a duplicate. As you can see (see link http://ideone.com/s2PvSB from my post), my code works correct, serialisation and deserialisation of my type work fine. I have a private setter on a property with collection type. It's  significant for a XmlSerializer. My question is "why SGen failed", not "why my type can not be serialized" - because it can.

Comment: Hmm, it is covered in [this KB-article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956847).  It is supposed to fail again.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like SGen broken again :o(

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange, as the code linked does indeed work for me.
It doesn't work if you change the `List<string>` to `string[]`. Is VS doing something strange with [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)? Maybe that allows your code to run normally, but `SGen` doesn't have access to the same trick?