# Other replacements for Serialization

Tags: java, c#

I have XML Configuration file and I need to load/save it so What are best ways to Parse XML Files for Load/Save configurations other than Serialization as I don't like the option of Serialization

Comment: why are `Java` and `C#` tagged?. For this use [JaxB](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAXB)

Comment: You just don't like Serialization? I don't like JavaScript and still have to do it... But whats bad about Serialization?

Comment: XML serialization is insecure , it works with public properties and classes, so no data protection thus force you to have exposed properties .

Answer (score 0):

For a Java application I serialized a pretty complex application state using [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/). For the most part this works extremely good. If the object is really simple this should not be a problem. Another simple alternative I often use to transfer data from Object <-> XML is [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) with annotations on the Objects, or if the XML structure is the master with an XML Schema from which the classes can be generated.

Comment: I will try that for Java , Do you know similar for c# ?

Answer (score 0):

For C# you could use [IXmlSerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx), or [DataContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx). Multiple answers can be found on SO using both these classes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802711/serializing-private-member-data) to see how to use `DataContract`.